# Passing array list from one method in a class to another method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

Have a function in tableview.m which gets me the start date and I add the strings in an array. now I want to pass this array to another method in different .m class called listview.m to retrieve the value in nsstring from the array.  How should I go about it? Any help is really appreciated.

```
- (id) getDate: (NSMutableArray *) classStart{

if ([self init]) {
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
    self.listArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
        const char *query_stmt = "select start_Date from test order by start_Date";

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                start_Date = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];
                [self.listArray addObject:start_Date];

            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);

            sqlite3_close(db);
            } 
    }
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any magic to this, just define a method in listview.m that will take the array as input.

Your definition in the listview.h might look like:

```
-(void)addListArray:(NSArray *)theArray;
```

Then from your class above you'd call it like:

```
[myListView addListArray:self.listArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out : Just changed the function header to

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getDate {
 return array;
 }
```

And call the method as array_two = [ListView getDate]; in the other class.

Both arrays are nsmutablearrays.